# how can i pass a variable that is calculated in real time w/ jQuery to a PayPal input form

Tags: jquery, paypal

I have a simple script where the user inputs a value and the web  page outputs the value w/ 2.9% added.  So far so good.  I am struggling with passing that value to the PayPal (input name "amount") form on the same page.  Tried several things but no luck so far.

```
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
                type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <label>payment amount:</label><input name="payment" id="payment" type="text" />
                   <br />
                  Above payment + convenience fee: $ <span id="result"></span>



    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="test@test.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="example description">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
<!--NEED HELP HERE W/ AMOUNT:--> <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.yoursite.com/returnpage.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but02.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make your payments with PayPal. It is free, secure, effective.">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/it_IT/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>


    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#payment').keyup(function(){
            $('#result').text($('#payment').val() * 1.029)

        });

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
var amt = $("#pament").val() * 1.029;
$('#result').text(amt);
$('#amount').val(amt);
```

Comment: tks, in  the mean time, I also had to convert to           toFixed(2)

Comment: I have this issue now. where the rounding works for most numbers but not some, for instance 1445.